# Error on insert data from another table into an existing partition

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to insert on a partitioned table like:

```
 insert into table select * from table@dblink
 where date = 201702003;
```

At first, I created the correct partition:
 TP_201702003 values (201702003)

And got this error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-14400: a chave de partição inserida não corresponde a nenhuma partição
14400. 00000 -  "inserted partition key does not map to any partition"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert a record into, a Range or Composite
           Range object, with a concatenated partition key that is beyond
           the concatenated partition bound list of the last partition -OR-
           An attempt was made to insert a record into a List object with
           a partition key that did not match the literal values specified
           for any of the partitions.
*Action:   Do not insert the key. Or, add a partition capable of accepting
           the key, Or add values matching the key to a partition specification
```

This is the only month with this problem.
Can you see anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where date = 201702003; -- Is 'date' a date column? Also, can you tag the database you are using, please?

Comment: It is 10G. However, I already identified the problem. I needed to create two subpartitions to pass the error.